# Simple Google Maps to Fancybox

Tags: jquery, forms, google-maps, fancybox, fancybox-2

Can anybody help with the following please:-

I need the below result to displayed in a fancybox is it possible please?

```
<h2>Get Directions</h2>
<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="fancybox">
<h6>Enter your starting address:</h6>
<input type="text" name="saddr" value="Enter Your Postcode"/>
<input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="52.444266,-1.648421" />
<input type="submit" value="Get Directions" class="button" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you may need to know what [URL parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) you can pass to a Google map so you can construct the URL you want to display in fancybox.

Second, add an ID (e.g.`id=myMapForm"`) to your form so you can manipulate it with jQuery
 :

```
 <form id="myMapForm" action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="fancybox">
    <h6>Enter your starting address:</h6>
    <input type="text" name="saddr" value="Enter Your Postcode" />
    <input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="52.444266,-1.648421" />
    <input type="submit" value="Get Directions" class="button" />
 </form>
```

Then, you can use the following script to :

- prevent submitting the form in a new window/tab
- get the input value from fields and storage them in variables
- construct the Google maps URL passing the variables as parameters
- open the resulting URL in fancybox

jQuery code :

```
$("#myMapForm").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sAdd = $(this).find("input[name=saddr]").val().replace(" ", "+");
    var dAdd = $(this).find("input[name=daddr]").val();
    var url  = "https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&q=from:+" + sAdd + "+to:+" + dAdd + "&ie=UTF8&saddr=" + sAdd + "&daddr=" + dAdd + "&center=" + dAdd + "&z=7&output=embed";
    $.fancybox(url, {
        type: "iframe"
    });
});
```

**Notice** that we added the `.replace()` method to the *source address* to convert any `spaces` into the plus sign (`+`). This is because the zip code can be something like `SW1A 0AA` (UK) and has to be converted to `SW1A+0AA` within the URL.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fcme9/)**

**NOTE** : `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+